# Best practice in use of static variables in C

Tags: c, variables, static

Global variables are generally considered to be a poor programming practice

In C, are static variables (i.e with module (file) scope) considered OK?

My thought was that member variables in an object oriented language cannot be much less dangerous than static variables in C and member variables seem to be considered to be a good thing.

I'm tiring of passing parameters through multiple functions and can see the attraction of static variables for this, especially if they are `const`.

But I'm keen to know if this is frowned upon - and also whether there is really any difference in level of programming naughtiness between a big object with a member variable used in several of its methods and a C file containing a few functions that utilize a static variable?

Comment: Why close it? It is a good, specific question that lots of programmers ought to be curious about.

Comment: many thanks for the answers that snuck in before the question was closed - they have helped to clarify the problem for me.

Comment: it's incredible how they close a question like this for being "not constructive" but on every "constructive" answer people will insert "but you *shouldnt* do this you *should* do this because yes that's how we do it in the real world"

Comment: the scope of 'good' SO questions is actually reasonably narrow and the boundaries are zealously enforced. I think this may also have been my 1st question and the moderators are definitely tougher on those with very low rep!

Answer (score 5):

Static (file-scope) variables in C are similar to static member variables in C++.

Any use of non-const static variables for communicating between functions makes those functions nonreentrant and thread-unsafe.  Thus, in general it would be preferable to pass the information via parameters.

A better analogue for non-static member variables is a struct member.  Just collect your "member variables" in a struct and pass that struct as a "this" parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference is: with member variables you can have multiple objects and each has its own member variable. With module scope static variables you have exactly one instance of the variable.

If you want to compare module level static variables and static class member variables then there is no real big difference. Both are instantiated exactly once, only the scope and access rules are different.

Answer (score 2):

One of the big disadvantage of static variable is "side-effects", ie when the result of a function doesn't only depends of the input parameters which makes testing and debugging harder .
A function without side effect is much easier to test because you can assume that every time you call a function with the same set of parameters you can expect the same result.

If you have a bug, you can check then if the result is correct accordingly to the input parameters. If then you realize the input parameters are wrong, then you can track in your code where/who as the parameters wrongly. If your function depends on a static variable and the static variables doesn't have the expected value , how do you track/find why and how it changes ?

So, if you want to use constant, then use proper constant (#DEFINE) or group your parameters into a structure and try avoid static variable as much as possible.
(at least #DEFINE value won't get corrupted in memory)

Answer (score 1):

Static variables are perhaps marginally better than globals, but not much. Being not as evil as global variables is not much of a commendation however!

When you have multiple threads or reentrant functions then they do not suffice. What's more using them as parameter passing mechanism will lead to code that is very hard to read and maintain. There are uses for static variables but I'd never use them for parameter passing. In some cases it can be better collecting parameters into a struct to be passed around.

Comment: It is true that threads or reentrant functions shouldn't access statics without synchronization objects, but that isn't the fault of the static variable itself. Also, there is a lot of things like callback functions, interrupts etc that don't have parameters. Then you don't have any other choice but static, no matter if you are writing C or C++.

Comment: @lundin question is specifically about using module statics as an alternative to parameter passing.

Comment: Yes, so why bring multi-threading into it? The OP didn't mention a platform or a purpose for the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use global or static variables, but use them with care. I'm not sure that module-wide static variables are much better than global ones.

In particular, having more than a dozen global variables in even a big program is probably poor taste (but that happens).

And you might prefer to group your static or global data in larger `struct`-s.

Comment: Why would it be poor taste? They are privately encapsulated and don't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: About poor taste, I was thinking of global (not static) variables. You can transmit static variables thru pointers, and you may sometimes have some strange bugs related to that. Of course, it depends...

Answer (score 1):

In the context you're trying to use them, module variables are probably a bad idea. The nice thing about passing everything by parameters is so that it's hard to get out-of-sync with your method calls. Each method does something and passes some component of that off to another method, so it's easy to trace - the variables are only live during the method call. It gets more difficult to debug if the variables exist somewhere else - things like using a stale variable go from impossible to rather likely.

Static variables are typically used as *flags* - a common one being a boolean that you set to change the mode of the whole module in a subtle way (a quasi-builtin one being DEBUG).